# Unique index on nested fields in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Are these schemas valid?

```
var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {type: String, required:true},
  last_name: {type: String, required: true},
  mother_name : {type: String, required: true},
  siblings:[{
    name:{type: String, required: true},
    age:{type:Number, required: true},
    school:{type:String, required:true}
  }]
});
```

And this

```
var WinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    event:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Event'},
    winners : [{
        student: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student'},
        position: {type:String, enum:["First","Second","Third","Consolation"]}
  }]
});

WinSchema.index({event:1,winners.student:1},{unique:true});

mongoose.model('Win',WinSchema);
```

Can we nest it as shown in StudentSchema?
Can we create a unique index on nested documents?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can nest it, see schema example [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and of course you can create a index on nested documents here is the [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents).

Comment: I think the index I have specified in the second schema is logically wrong. If not syntactically wrong

Comment: It is logically right.You can try in the mongo shell.I have tried.